# Looping through PHP object results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and trying to figure out how to loop through an object - essentially a query call - to display the results. I have the following:

Here is the function in my class:

```
    // getDefinitionsByCategoryID
    public static function getDefinitionsByCategoryID($categoryID=0) {
        return self::find_by_sql("SELECT dictionaryID, dictionaryCategoryID, term, kanji, termEnglishName, shortDefinition, definition FROM dictionary WHERE dictionaryCategoryID = {$categoryID} ORDER BY term");
    }
```

find_by_sql is this:

```
public static function find_by_sql($sql="") {
        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query($sql);

        // returns an array of objects
        return $result_set;
    }
```

Here is the object creation on the page where the results will be displayed:

```
$catDefinitions = Dictionary::getDefinitionsByCategoryID($_GET['categoryID']);
```

And here is the loop I'm trying to use:

```
               while ($catDefRow = $database->fetch_array($catDefinitions)) {
                    echo('<li><a href="dictionary.php?definitionID=' . trim($catDefRow["dictionaryID"]) .'">' . trim($catDefRow["term"]) . '</a><br /><div class="smallFont">' . $catDefRow["kanji"] . '</div></li>');
                }
```

Quite simply, it's not working. (To be fair, I've been using the lynda.com tutorials to help me learn this.)

I have another function in a different class - just for reference - that I've been using successfully:

```
    public static function getRyuhaByID($ryuhaID=0) {
        global $database;
        $result_set_ryuha1 = self::find_by_sql("SELECT ryuhaID, ryuhaName, ryuhaKanji, ryuhaEnglishName, isRyuha FROM ryuha WHERE ryuhaID = {$ryuhaID} LIMIT 1");

        $found_ryuha1 = $database->fetch_array($result_set_ryuha1);
        return $found_ryuha1;
    }
```

They look different, obviously. But, I'm trying to figure out if the syntax in this above example is the same syntax I should be following for the first. It seems that when I am only expecting one result (as in the example above) it works fine, and when I'm expecting all results in a table without a query variable being passed the first example works fine, but when I am expecting multiple rows returned from the db the "return self:: ..." syntax and also passing a query variable, it doesn't work.

I hope this all makes sense; I know the more information given the better. This has been bugging me for a week now, so anything to both help me resolve this specific issue and learn more about PHP programming would be greatly appreciated.

Right now I'm in a rush to get this project completed, so I know I'm taking a hybrid approach and not using strict OO principles.

Comment: You say it's  not working, but what's the error? I'm not seeing an error leaping out at me (although I might see one if I look longer), so it would help to know the exact PHP error.

Comment: Well, I hate to say it, but I'm not sure how to get errors to display. I'm getting a blank page, which says to me it's not working. When I take the code out, the rest of the page displays.

Comment: Blank page means you probably got a fatal error, and you didn't set up PHP on your server to emit errors. Turn this on on your development machine, otherwise you're practically coding blind.